# Node Swapping in Linked List

Tags: c, nodes

I am new to C. I am trying to swap two nodes using linked lists. Not sure what is wrong. It gives me an error saying

> "temp" is undeclared.

Also, what could I change in this code to swap not only char but int as well?

```
struct lnode {
int some_line;
int count;
char* some_word;
struct lnode* next;
   };

   void swapNodes(struct lnode** head, struct lnode* n1, struct lnode* n2);



   int main()
   {

     struct lnode* head = NULL;
     struct lnode* node0 = newCharNode(&head,"this is");
     struct lnode* node1 = newCharNode(&head,"programming");
     swapNodes(&head,node0,node1);
     getchar();
     return 0;
   }



   void swapNodes(struct lnode** head, struct lnode* n1, struct lnode* n2)
  {
    struct lnode* current = (*head);
    struct lnode* temp;

        while((current != NULL) && (current->next != NULL))
    {
           temp->some_word = n1->some_word;
       n1->some_word = n2->some_word;
       n2->some_word = temp->some_word;
    }
       printf("%s %s",n1,n2);
       current = (current->next)->next;
  }

   struct lnode* newCharNode(struct lnode** head, char* myword) {
   struct lnode* new_node = (struct lnode*) malloc(sizeof(struct lnode));
   new_node ->some_word = myword;
   new_node ->next = (*head);
   (*head) = new_node;
  }
```

Comment: After fixing missing includes and the lack of a prototype for `newCharNode`, I was not able to reproduce the compile error you are getting.

Comment: i am including the files necessary, i get the error for temp which i understand, but how to fix it, i dont know that. Help is appreciated.

Comment: swapNodes seems to imply simply swapping the content of two nodes, but the function is doing something much more complex. Also, the while loop either never enters the loop body, or loops forever, since the pointer 'current' is never modified in the loop.

If you just want to swap the content of two nodes, all you need is to pass pointers to the two nodes, swap everything in the structs except the link pointer, and return.

Answer (score 1):

In void swapNodes()

```
temp->some_word
```

here temp is only a uninitialized pointer and you can't make that assignment.